# retrieve data from database using php to android

Tags: php, android, mysql

I have three major tables in my database, called **place**, **guideinfo** and **city**. I enter a city name using a android app, and there is a `cityID` associated with that city name. Each three tables have the `cityID` column.

Below is my php:

```
<?php
$con=new mysqli("dsfsdf","fsfs","Wpraneet","a1575184_touri");

$city=$_POST['city'];

if($con->connect_error){
     die( "Failed to connect MYSQL");
     }
//$sql1="SELECT * 
//FROM place, guideinfo, city
//WHERE place.city_cityID = city.cityID
//AND city.cityID = guideinfo.city_cityID
//AND place.city_cityID = guideinfo.city_cityID
//AND cityName =  '".$city."'
//LIMIT 4;";

$sql1="SELECT * FROM place a JOIN guideinfo b ON a.city_cityID = b.city_cityID JOIN city c ON a.city_cityID = c.cityID WHERE cityName =  '".$city."' LIMIT 4;";
$result1 = $con->query ($sql1);

if ($result1-> num_rows> 0) {
    //output data of each row
    while($row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $row1['placeName']; 
    echo "_";
    echo $row1['placeType'];
    echo "_";
    echo $row1['lat'];
    echo "_";
    echo $row1['lng'];
    echo "_";
    echo $row1['shtDes'];
    echo "_";
    echo $row1['GID'];
    echo "_";
    echo $row1['GName'];
    echo "_";
    echo $row1['Category'];
    echo "_";
    echo $row1['TelephoneNo'];
    echo "_"; 
    }     
   }

  $con->close();
  ?>
```

In my app I want to retrieve data from *four* places and *four* guides in that city that has been entered and using google maps, mark those four places.

I have used two queries and both are mentioned in the code. My question is when there is only one tuple in `guideinfo` table relevant to city which was entered, the map will show all the four markers on the map.

But if there are two tuples in the `guideinfo` table relevant to city, the map will show **two** markers.

I want to show all the **four** markers and get details of four guides.

I think there must be a error in mysql query; what should I change?

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble following your description of the problem.

Can you tell me more specific how your expected result looks like? I don't see how you want details of 4 guides when only 2 are available.

Comment: yeah. suppose there are 4 guides details in the table. then the google map only showing 1 marker. If there are only 1 guide details in the table google map show all the 4 markers then i tried to print the data which came from data base. i put 4 separate spaces for show the details of guides(only one tuple in the data base) all of the 4 spaces shown the details of that single tuple. 
my matter is all if i put more tuples in the guideinfo table google map not showing all the markers. 
1 guide tuple-4 markers,    
2 guide tuple-2 markers,    
4 guide tuple-1 marker

Comment: I think problem in the query which written for get the datas from those 3 tables

Comment: Could you share some example Data, I still can not really follow your description http://sqlfiddle.com